# Which source is correct regarding a visa exemption, the Embassy or IATA? (Case)

Tags: visas, embassies

According to IATA, a citizen of X country can travel to Bosnia using a Cyprus Visa (multiple entry). However, following a visit to Bosnia's Embassy, the officer responded the following: You have to obtain a Schengen visa to enter Bosnia.

Then, I informed her that once I used the Cyprus visa to visit Croatia. She replied saying: So your Cyprus visa is valid for Schengen because Croatia does not have border controls with EU. As such, you can use your Cyprus visa to enter Bosnia.

I am not confident in her answer. What do you advise me in this regard? I wish to travel to Bosnia using this visa instead of applying for a new visa just for 4 days’ visit!

Comment: "Croatia does not have border controls with EU" is false.

Comment: What does "(Case)" mean in the title?

Comment: I have seen cases in which both Timatic and embassies have given incorrect information. But while it's been quite rare to find an error in Timatic, I see embassies giving wrong information all the time. In either case, to be sure, you would have to go back to official sources from the country's foreign ministry or directly to their laws and regulations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msb.gov.ba/inf_za_strance/default.aspx?id=14555&langTag=en-US) is an official Bosnian government source, from the Ministry of Security.  In reading it, keep in mind that Cyprus is, as you note in a comment, an EU country.  I have added emphasis to the text to call attention to the places where it mentions "EU country":

> **Visa-free regime for the Multiple Entry Schengen Visas or Residence Permits in the Schengen or EU Member States**
>
> Nationals of the countries having a visa-free regime with BiH may enter BiH with their passports without obligation to obtain a visa for entry, exit, transit and stay on the territory of Bosnia and Herzegovina provided they hold a valid multiple entry Schengen visa **or a visa of a** [sic] **EU country** or an appropriate residence permit in a Schengen or EU country.
>
> These provisions apply only if a holder of a Schengen visa/EU country visa or of appropriate residence permit in the Schengen area or EU country, arrives to Bosnia and Herzegovina from:
>
> - the Schengen area;
> - a Member State of the European Union;
> - a country having signed a readmission agreement with BiH, which has entered into force.
>
> In this case, a total stay in BiH cannot exceed 90 days within the 180-day period, starting from the date of first entry, provided that one uninterrupted stay in BiH cannot be longer than 15 days and within a period of validity of the visa or residence permit issued by a Schengen or EU country.

Answer (score -2):

Bosnia, Croatia and Cyprus are not Schengen Countries

- dual or multiple entry Schengen C-Visa can be used to enter these three countries
- the national visas or residence permits of European Union Countries can be used to enter Bosnia
- IATA claim: true since Cyprus is a European Union Country
- [Bosnia](http://msb.gov.ba/inf_za_strance/default.aspx?id=14555&langTag=en-US)'s Embassy claim 1: correct, you can use a dual or multiple Schengen Visa to enter Bosnia
- Bosnia's Embassy claim 2 and 3: the meaning of the statement is not clear to me, but [Croatia](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) does allow entry with a Cyprus national visa

---

For visits to Cyprus and Bosnia

- a multiple entry Schengen Visa should be applied for

  - a dual entry may not be sufficient
- could find no statement that a Cyprus national visa is valid for other Schengen Countries

Comment: According to Timatic, Visa Exemptions to Bosnia:
Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Monaco, Romania, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 30 days. The visa must be valid for the period of intended stay. A total of 90 days is granted within 6 months.

Comment: @Alex I could not find confirmation of this at (what I assume) is an official Bosnia government site. http://msb.gov.ba/inf_za_strance/default.aspx?id=14555&langTag=en-US

Comment: Please see the paragraph under "Visa-free regime for the Multiple Entry Schengen Visas or Residence Permits in the Schengen or EU Member States". Cyprus is a EU member state.

Comment: @Alex It would be helpful for you to provide the URL of the page you're referring to.

Comment: @Alex ok, that might work. And for Croatia Cyprus is meantioned by name. Wiil adapt answer.

Comment: @David I was referring to this https://www.emirates.com/ae/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx which is based on Timatic database

Comment: @MarkJohnson can you pls clarify what do you mean by “that might work”?

Comment: @Alex more of a first impression, but it is clear: **holder of a Schengen visa/EU country visa**

Comment: "For visits to Cyprus and Bosnia a multiple entry Schengen Visa should be applied for": No Schengen country will grant a Schengen visa for the purpose of a visit to Cyprus and Bosnia.  You cannot find a statement that a Cyprus national visa is valid for Schengen countries because it isn't.

Comment: @Alex my point is that the recommendation to apply for a multiple entry Schengen visa is poorly conceived, because it can only be useful if someone is planning a trip to a Schengen country in addition to Bosnia and/or Cyprus.  Someone who wants to visit only Bosnia and/or Cyprus *cannot get a Schengen visa.*

Comment: @phoog So I should be confident that a Cyprus visa, multiple entry, can indeed allow me access to Bosnia? (Citizenship has been checked too). Timatic always accurate, I used it to visit Croatia last year using a Romanian and then Cyprus visa.

Comment: @phoog 1) how many direct flights are there between Cyprus and Bosnia? Travel through Greece is reasonable assumption. Source not possible requested. 2) Source for that also. Restricted stated because I found none.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am only familiar with the airline schedule in Sarajevo.  There are no direct flights between Cyprus and Sarajevo, perhaps excluding charters.  Direct flights between Sarajevo and Athens, twice weekly, began last spring.  There may be flights to Banja Luka that I don't know about.  But direct flights aren't particularly relevant to this question.  One could use a Cypriot visa to enter Bosnia via Germany or Austria (flights from Munich and Vienna) or Croatia (by air or land).  See my answer.

Comment: @phoog what if I want to travel via flydubai (from Dubai airport)?

Comment: @Alex then I suppose you'd have to find out whether there is a readmission agreement.